# mingw32 compiler giving error with -lcrypt

Tags: c, compiler-errors, cs50, mingw32, crypt

I have been trying to make my `crack.c` code work on my Windows 10 laptop. The code runs on CS50 IDE (online IDE) without any errors. However, when I try to compile the code on my laptop using mingw32 on command line, the compiler is giving me an error:

```
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot 
 find -lcrypt collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The code uses [`crypt()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html) from the Linux C library. I tried to link the compiler to this by `-lcrypt` but apparently it does not exist.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: MinGW is a 'Minimal GNU on Windows' system.  It doesn't necessarily provide all the libraries that GNU generally provides.  Check whether you can find a `libcrypt` for MinGW, or consider whether you want Cygwin instead — that does provide better Unix (Linux) compatibility and has libraries such as `libcrypt` available.

Answer (score 0):

MinGW doesn't generally come with libcrypt. You'll have to either find a Windows version of the static library (I don't know of one), or alternatively, you can include the source code for `crypt(3)`in your project.

This version of [crypt.c](http://michael.dipperstein.com/crypt/crypt3.c) has worked for me in the past. (Code is in the public domain). It's a fairly old version, but it suffices.

In the event the link rots away, a simple web search should yield several examples, as the source is widely available, with varying levels of licensing.